# How to split the string using '^' this special character in java?

Tags: java

I want to split the following string "Good^Evening" i used split option it is not split the value. please help me.

This is what I've been trying:

```
String Val = "Good^Evening";
String[] valArray = Val.Split("^");
```

Comment: Please show us the code that didn't work.

Comment: String Val = "Good^Evening";String[] valArray = Val.Split("^");

Comment: @ManoharKulanthaivel Thanks, but please edit your question with that so it's easy to reference.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'm assuming you did something like:

```
String[] parts = str.split("^");
```

That doesn't work because the argument to `split` is actually a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), where `^` has a special meaning.  Try this instead:

```
String[] parts = str.split("\\^");
```

The `\\` is really equivalent to a single `\` (the first `\` is required as a Java escape sequence in string literals).  It is then a special character in regular expressions which means "use the next character literally, don't interpret its special meaning".

Answer (score 7):

The regex you should use is "\^" which you write as `"\\^"` as a Java String literal; i.e.

```
String[] parts = "Good^Evening".split("\\^");
```

The regex needs a '\' escape because the caret character ('^') is a meta-character in the regex language.  The 2nd '\' escape is needed because '\' is an escape in a String literal.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String str = "Good^Evening";
String newStr = str.replaceAll("[^]+", "");
```