# Java String.split not working

Tags: java, regex

I have a string in following format:

```
CT-d0712728-867d-4cc4-bd0c-b2a679b8385f~#$~2012-10-16 02:13:27 PM
```

Can I use `String.split("~#$~")` or do I have to use StringTokenizer? I will have ONLY 2 parameters in above string, that's why I was trying to use String.Split("~#$~") but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551489/how-to-split-the-string-using-this-special-character-in-java

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  Did you capture the results into a `String[]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$` is [special character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) in regex (it means "end of a line"). To make it simple literal you need to escape it, for example  with

- `"\\$"`,
- `"[$]"`
- or using quotations `"\\Q$\\E"`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `split()` method takes the paremeters as `Regex`, and `$` is special meta-character in `Regex`. You need to escape the `$` sign: -

```
    System.out.println(str.split("~#\\$~")[0]);
    System.out.println(str.split("~#\\$~")[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
String s = "CT-d0712728-867d-4cc4-bd0c-b2a679b8385f~#$~2012-10-16 02:13:27 PM";

Arrays.toString(s.split("~#\\$~"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "CT-d0712728-867d-4cc4-bd0c-b2a679b8385f~#$~2012-10-16 02:13:27 PM";
String[] pieces = str.split("~#\\$~");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using String.split(). No need to use  StringTokenizer. See then below example.

```
String s="CT-d0712728-867d-4cc4-bd0c-b2a679b8385f~#$~2012-10-16 02:13:27 PM";
        String test[]=s.split("\\~\\#\\$\\~");
        System.out.println(test[0]);
        System.out.println(test[1]);
```

Let me know i you have any questions.