# Java : split a string that containing special characters

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string like `||81|||01||` and I want to split the string with `|` symbol.

I had done this way,

```
String str = "||81|||01||";
System.out.println(str .split("\\|").length); //printing 6 . But I am expecting 8
```

what is wrong with this code? | How can I split this string with that character so that I will get expected length (`8`)?;

Comment: Why you think 8 as expected result ?

Comment: @NoobUnChained if there are `n` delimiters, the string should be split into `n+1` parts. In the given input there are `7` pipes, so there should be `8` results.

Comment: Introduce a space at beginning and end : `" ||81|||01|| "` to get the expected result ;)

Comment: @NoobUnChained that's an odd hack, seeing that Java provides you the option to change the behavior using an additional argument for `split`, don't you think?

Comment: @NoobUnChained: No. You'll get a different result (space instead of an empty string).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Print:

`System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.split("\\|")));`

And you'll understand why it's printing 6.

You can try doing what you want using public [String[] split(String regex, int limit)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is
>   applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array.

So you should do:

```
System.out.println(str.split("\\|", -1).length);
```

Now, printing the array will print:

`[, , 81, , , 01, , ]` as you expected.

Answer (score 11):

Using [`split("\\|")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) is the same as [`split("\\|", 0)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), where the limit parameter `0` tells the function "omit trailing empty strings". So you are missing the last two empty strings. Use the two-argument version and supply a negative number to obtain all parts (even trailing empty ones):

```
str.split("\\|", -1)
```

Comment: Dear downvoter, would you care to leave a comment so I can improve the answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use string.split(Pattern.quote("|"),-1) for spliting a string on a special character.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: example to split "||81|||01||" based on the special character '|' then you can use
`String s="||81|||01||";
String array[]=s.split(Pattern.quote("|"),-1)
`
length of the array thus obtained will be 8.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
str.split("\\|", -1)
```

The second parameter is `limit`.  From the javadoc:

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is
>   applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If
>   the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at
>   most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and
>   the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched
>   delimiter. If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as
>   many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero
>   then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array
>   can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Answer (score 1):

`str.split("\\|", -1)` will do the necessary.
Possible duplicate : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551489/how-to-split-the-string-using-this-special-character-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

`String str = "||81|||01||";`
`System.out.println(str.split("\\|", 8).length);`

The second argument to split specifies maximum number of matches. Single argument split is like invoking split(str, 0) which leaves out trailing strings. See javadoc of both for more explaination.

Comment: using `8` is quite inflexible. if you just use a negative argument (like the other answers), you'll simply get all parts, no matter how many `|` there are in `str`