# how to ignore newlines for split function

Tags: java, split, newline

I am splitting the string using `^` char. The String which I am reading, is coming from some external source. This string contains some `\n` characters.

The string may look like:

```
Hi hello^There\nhow are\nyou doing^9987678867abc^popup
```

when I am splitting like below, why the array length is coming as `2` instead of `4`:

```
String[] st = msg[0].split("^");
st.length //giving "2" instead of "4"
```

It look like, split is ignoring after `\n`.

How can I fix it without replacing `\n` to some other character.

Comment: If you read the Javadoc, you'll find that `split` works with regular expressions, and `^` has special meaning in a regex. Escape the character. `\\^`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the string parameter for split is interpreted as regular expression.
So you have to escape the char and use:

```
st.split("\\^")
```

[see this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551489/how-to-split-the-string-using-this-special-character-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split by `^` only, then

```
String[] st = msg[0].split("\\^");
```

If I read your question correctly, you want to split by `^` and `\n` characters, so this would suffice.

```
String[] st = msg[0].split("[\\^\\\\n]");
```

This considers that `\n` literally exists as 2 characters in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the `^` character. Use `msg[0].split("\\^")` instead.

[`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) considers its argument as regular expression. And as `^` has a special meaning when it comes to regular expressions, you need to *escape* it to use its literal representation.

Answer (score 0):

"^" it's know as regular expression by the JDK.
To avoid this confusion you need to modify the code as below
old code = msg[0].split("^")
new code = msg[0].split("\\^")