# How to split a string with special characters `}`, `/`, `-` and `{` in Java

Tags: java, string, split, special-characters

I had been following the thread [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java) and had been successful.

But in the current usecase the `String` I am dealing with contains the special characters.

I am having a `String` as `https://{domain name}/{type of data}/4583236-{name-of-perpetrators}` and I want to extract `4583236` out of it.

The QA [How to split the string using '^' this special character in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551489/how-to-split-the-string-using-this-special-character-in-java) is more or less related to the Question I already have mentioned previously but doesn't helps in my usecase.

My program is throwing **`PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition`** randomly on either of the special characters.

Code Block :

```
    String current_url = "https://{domain name}/{type of data}/4583236-{name-of-perpetrators}";
    String[] urlParts = current_url.split("type of data}/");
    String mySuburl = urlParts[1];
    String[] suburl = mySuburl.split("-{name-of-perpetrators");
    String mytext = suburl[0];
    System.out.println(mytext);
```

**Error Stack Trace :**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition
{name-of-perpetrators
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.split(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.split(Unknown Source)
    at demo.TextSplit.main(TextSplit.java:18)
```

Comment: why not split on "/", and after that take the correct startingpoint. there you can (more) easily extract the numerical value.

Comment: @Stultuske Thanks for the suggestion. But splitting with `/` & `-` doesn't prints any thing.

Comment: You don't actually need to split several times. Two `indexOf` and `substring` are better and probably more performant.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I missed out your suggestion. Can you please provide me an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [`Pattern.quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) to avoid escaping character by character, It will do that free for you :

```
String[] suburl = mySuburl.split(Pattern.quote("-{name-of-perpetrators"));
```

Comment: `Pattern.quote("-{name-of-perpetrators")` seems outstanding !!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The argument for [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) is a regex. So, you need to escape the special characters used in regex like `{`. `{}` is used to denote repetition in regex and hence the error `Illegal repetition`.

```
String[] suburl = mySuburl.split("-\\{name-of-perpetrators");
```

If you don't want the argument for `split` to be a regex, use [`Pattern.quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) to avoid escaping as [@YCF_L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48170061/1421222) suggested.

```
String[] suburl = mySuburl.split(Pattern.quote("-{name-of-perpetrators"));
```

Comment: `split("-\\{name-of-perpetrators");` was perfect !!! Thanks a lot for the beautiful explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There is literally no reason to use something as complex as regular expression patterns for something as simple as finding literal string contained in another string.

Using `indexOf` and `substring` is sufficient:

```
String text = "https://{domain name}/{type of data}/4583236-{name-of-perpetrators}";
String searchStart = "{type of data}/";
String searchEnd = "-{name-of-perpetrators}";
int start = text.indexOf(searchStart) + searchStart.length();
int end = text.indexOf(searchEnd, start);

String expected = "4583236";
assertEquals(expected, text.substring(start, end));
```

Obviously, if at any point input text might not have exactly this format, then this approach might fail, for example by making `start` or `end` variables negative. If that is the case, you should check for it and handle it appropriately.

Comment: Thanks. Great idea beyond any doubt. But I won't be knowing what exactly the expected value is. Hence my question was how can I extract the number.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. Calling `substring` with the indices does extract the proper number from initial text, as shown by the test What else do you want to know? How to convert `String` to a number?